# Amazon API JSON Response

Tags: json, xml, amazon-web-services, api, response

I am using Amazon `AWSECommerceService API` for getting some info from the Amazon site and use them for my page/site.I am sending a REST request and the response which i am getting is in the XMl format.  Is there any way in which i am get the response in JSON format.Have googled a lot but was unable to find a exact solution.Rather than looking for some XMl to JSON parsers i am looking for some inbuilt methods/parameters which we can give and get the response accordingly.
My REST URL looks like this:

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAID6RVE3PNXNOSVWA&AssociateTag=8329-3607-2382&ItemPage=1&Keywords=Famous&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=SalesRank&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&Sort=salesrank&Timestamp=2014-03-06T06%3A19%3A33Z&Version=2014-02-10&Signature=m8ygF4nUMUGANUUwi44DUb80OXdMEMugauNkzwEMOys%3D.
```

The above URL wont work as the signature is expired. but i am getting response with this format of URL when i am running in my application.
Needs help as dying to implement the same from last 2 days.

Comment: Have you looked at specifying `application/json` as `contentType` parameter noted in documentation at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CommonRequestParameters.html ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a python module called boto3 using which the response comes in JSON format.
For more info see boto3 documnentation